# Getting subscriberid, oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for Google, yahoo and facebook in android

Tags: facebook, oauth, yahoo, facebook-oauth

I am working on the application where I have to get the subscriberid, oauth_token and oauth_token_secret for Google, Yahoo and Facebook. How can I do this?

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Use the APIs described on the page of google, yahoo, fb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for all OAuth system you need to follow the below mentioned steps

1. Register you application with them and get client_key and secret_key
2. When user want to get authenticate them self pass on the `secret key` and `client_key` to   OAuth system to get `AuthorizationUrl` which will contain request token.
3. Redirect user to these provider and once user authenticate them, OAuth system will redirect back user to your application.
4. They will send a `verification code`, use that `verification_code` along with the request token got in step2 to get `Access token`.
5. Once you have `Access_Token` you can interact with the oAuth system to access user data.

out of them only step 3 is where user will be in directly engaged and for rest of steps things will happen behind the scene.
Each service provide has a well defined documentation like at which URL to send request to get request token/Access Token and what they expect in request data what they will send back in conformation etc.

here are the details

[Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html)

[Yahoo OAuth documentation](http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/)

[FaceBook OAuth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/)

Though i have never worked with mobile application but the protocol is more or less same.
My suggestion is to use some API to achieve this.

hope will help you